# Local notifications not showing up when device is rebooted (or similar state) Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, notifications, localnotification

I'm a bit new so I have a simple question, I have created a Xamarin.Android app and I have used local notifications with alarm manager, broadcast receivers, etc to schedule them, the problem that I have is that my scheduled notifications are not being showed when the device is rebooted, or completely off state and turn on again. My questions are:

Is that a problem inside Android? 
otherwise 
How can I solve it?

I hope help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*By default, all alarms are canceled when a device shuts down.*

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

> By default, all alarms are canceled when a device shuts down. To prevent this from happening, you can design your application to automatically restart a repeating alarm if the user reboots the device. This ensures that the AlarmManager will continue doing its task without the user needing to manually restart the alarm.

You need to monitor for BOOT_COMPLETE and re-set your alarms.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


<receiver android:name=".SampleBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver:

```
class SampleBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") {
            // Re-set the alarm here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, right now i'm not in  my house (so I cant prove your answer) but with the creation of the reciever (both, on class and definifition on mainfest) as well as permisions, the broadcast receiver, on the OnReceiver method should be executed when device is rebooted, right?

Comment: ok thanks, other thing, in the <receiver>, on the "android.name", i have to put all the path of my receiver right, example, "AppName.Namespace.Broadcast", or im wrong?

Comment: I've updated my post, could you please check what am I doing wrong please, note, im using Xamarin.Android

Comment: please check the new post over: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60076532/rebooting-receiver-not-working-android-xamarin-android/60077095#60077095