# “Rebooting receiver” not working android [Xamarin.Android]

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, xamarin.android, toast

I am trying to implement a broadcast receiver that gets the broadcast when the device has been rebooted, but is not working (it is supposed to send me a toast when the device has rebooted) with the following code:

Broadcast receiver:

```
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    public class RebootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (Intent.ActionBootCompleted.Equals(intent.Action))
            {
                Toast.MakeText(
                    context,
                    "Your app has been rebooted!",
                    ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".RebootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
```

And permission inside the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Hope help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, the answer of @FreakyAli has also helped in fact of getting the solution

Create Service:

```
[Service(Name = "com.companyname.app.RebootService")]
    public class RebootService : Service
    {
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Service STARTED!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();

            Toast.MakeText(this, "Service STOPED", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Create BroadcastReciver:

```
 [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled =true, Name ="com.companyname.Sortex.RebootReceiver")]
        [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
        public class RebootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
            }
        }
```

register Service and BroadcastReceiver on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="com.companyname.app.RebootService"/>
<receiver android:name="com.companyname.app.RebootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Call the service on the OnReceive method of the Broadcast receiver:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(RebootService));
context.StartService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: @FreakyAli need to wait one day to mark my answer a it

Comment: I know what I meant was whenever you can!

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a problem with your broadcast receiver follow these steps and see if it works:

Add the manifest entry for the boot permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Add the receiver and use a full qualifed name:

```
<receiver android:name="com.yourpackagename.app.BootBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add a `Name` parameter to the `BroadcastReceiverAttribute` for the fully qualified name that you used in the manifest

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.yourpackagename.app.BootBroadcastReceiver", Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]    
public class BootBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
 {
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (Intent.ActionBootCompleted.Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(
                context,
                "Your app has been rebooted!",
                ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck feel free to get back if you have queries

Comment: I have done it the way you have established but my error is still the same, I have rebooted my device again and again and doesnt show me up anything, otherwise, now, the app when i have rebooted my device pops up me an alert saying: "AppName has stoped", any suggestion?

Comment: Really thanks to you , your code save my day